# Express js session always returns false for isAuthenticated

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I've been fighting this issue for about a week now and have tried everything I can think of and have gotten now where.  Below is code that I've stripped down to show the problem.

When I hit `/secure/` it redirects me properly to the `/oauth/` url.  Then when I click "login" the authorization and callback happen properly and the `valid_login` method is called.  In this method `req.isAuthenticated()` returns true.  The redirect then happens back to `/secure/` and when ensure_authenticated is called, `req.isAuthenticated()` always returns false.

```
/*jslint browser: true, regexp: true, es5: true, nomen: true */
/*global require, process, console, __dirname */

var express = require('express');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var passport = require('passport');
var SalesforceStrategy = require('passport-salesforce').Strategy;

var session_options = {
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: true
    }
};

/*jslint unparam: true*/
var valid_login = function (req, res) {
    'use strict';
    res.redirect('/secure/');
};

var ensure_authenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    'use strict';
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }

    res.redirect('/oauth/');
};
/*jslint unparam: false*/

var SalesforceApps = function () {
    'use strict';

    var self = this;

    self.setupVariables = function () {
        self.ipaddress = '127.0.0.1';
        self.port = 5000;

        /*jslint unparam: true*/
        passport.use(new SalesforceStrategy({
            clientID: process.env.SALESFORCE_CLIENTID,
            clientSecret: process.env.SALESFORCE_CLIENTSECRET,
            callbackURL: process.env.SALESFORCE_CALLBACKURL
        }, function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            return done(null, profile);
        }));
        /*jslint unparam: false*/

        passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
            done(null, user);
        });

        passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
            done(null, user);
        });
    };

    self.initializeServer = function () {
        self.app = express();

        self.app.set('trust proxy', 1);
        self.app.use(expressSession(session_options));
        self.app.use(passport.initialize());
        self.app.use(passport.session());

        //Authorization
        /*jslint unparam: true*/
        self.app.get('/oauth', function (req, res) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            res.send('<html><body><a href="/oauth/authorize">login</a></body></html>');
        });
        self.app.get('/oauth/authorize', passport.authenticate('salesforce', {session: false}));
        self.app.get('/oauth/callback', passport.authenticate('salesforce', {session: false}), valid_login);

        //Applications
        self.app.get('/secure/', ensure_authenticated, function (req, res) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            res.send('<html><body>secure</body></html>');
        });
        /*jslint unparam: false*/
    };

    self.initialize = function () {
        self.setupVariables();
        self.initializeServer();
    };

    self.start = function () {
        self.app.listen(self.port, self.ipaddress, function () {
            console.log('%s: Node server started on %s:%d ...', Date(Date.now()), self.ipaddress, self.port);
        });
    };
};

var zapp = new SalesforceApps();
zapp.initialize();
zapp.start();
```

I have tried putting a session store in place, I've tried waiting until nextTick to redirect, I've tried practically all the variants of the `session_options` I could and nothing has worked.  I can see the cookie is stored in the browser and if I output the value of `req.session` in `ensure_authenticated`, stuff exists in there.

Comment: Are you running this server locally? I'm not totally sure, but it could be that you're using secure cookies on a local server instance. You might want to try conditionally setting cookies to unsecure for development. https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookiesecure

Comment: @KevinO'Hara I've tried without secure cookies and it didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that passing `{session: false}` will make it not record the session.  Changing `{session: true}` will cause the session to be stored and everything to work as expected.  This was a "error" in the passport-salesforce documentation where it is included in their example code.